# How to ignore webpack errors during war packaging

Tags: webpack, jhipster

I'm using Jhipster to build a webapp, and I need to create a war file to deliver it in production.
I'm running the following command: mvn -Pprod,war clean verify

I get a lot of errors from npm/webpack, such as this one:

```
[INFO] ERROR in D:/maven-repo/zNouveau_Dossier/eclipse-workspace/research/node_modules/react-dropzone-uploader/dist/utils.ts
[INFO] ERROR in D:/maven-repo/zNouveau_Dossier/eclipse-workspace/research/node_modules/react-dropzone-uploader/dist/utils.ts(77,26):
[INFO] no-object-literal-type-assertion: Type assertion on object literals is forbidden, use a type annotation instead.
[INFO]
[INFO] ERROR in D:/maven-repo/zNouveau_Dossier/eclipse-workspace/research/node_modules/react-dropzone-uploader/dist/utils.ts
[INFO] ERROR in D:/maven-repo/zNouveau_Dossier/eclipse-workspace/research/node_modules/react-dropzone-uploader/dist/utils.ts(77,73):
[INFO] semicolon: Missing semicolon
[INFO]
...
```

which prevent me from building the war package:

```
[ERROR] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[ERROR] npm ERR! errno 2
[ERROR] npm ERR! frontlinemedia@0.0.0 webpack: `node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js "--config" "webpack/webpack.prod.js" "--profile"`
[ERROR] npm ERR! Exit status 2
[ERROR] npm ERR!
[ERROR] npm ERR! Failed at the frontlinemedia@0.0.0 webpack script.
[ERROR] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[ERROR] npm ERR!     ...\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-09T08_44_47_451Z-debug.log
[ERROR] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[ERROR] npm ERR! errno 2
[ERROR] npm ERR! frontlinemedia@0.0.0 webpack:prod:main: `npm run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile`
[ERROR] npm ERR! Exit status 2
[ERROR] npm ERR!
[ERROR] npm ERR! Failed at the frontlinemedia@0.0.0 webpack:prod:main script.
[ERROR] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[ERROR] npm ERR!     ...\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-09T08_44_47_503Z-debug.log
[ERROR] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[ERROR] npm ERR! errno 2
[ERROR] npm ERR! frontlinemedia@0.0.0 webpack:prod: `npm run cleanup && npm run webpack:prod:main`
[ERROR] npm ERR! Exit status 2
[ERROR] npm ERR!
[ERROR] npm ERR! Failed at the frontlinemedia@0.0.0 webpack:prod script.
[ERROR] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[ERROR] npm ERR!     ...\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-09T08_44_47_561Z-debug.log
```

I'm using npm 6.9.0, node v10.16.1, Jhipster > 5.8

How can I ignore those errors (some of these errors come from installed modules, such as react-dropzone-uploader, and I cannot fix them) and build the war package?

Comment: If you did not change anything in generated project you should rather open an issue against jhioster on github

Comment: Well, i installed some npm modules, these are npm commands that fail. That's why I was asking help here.